# Can I use many times of @BeforeClass in one TestNG case?

Tags: testng

```
public class TestBase{
    @BeforeClass
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {}

    @BeforeClass
    protected void setUp2() throws Exception {}

    @Test
    public void queryAcquirerInfoById(){
    }
}
```

If I use twice '@BeforeClass' at one TestNG class,What is the order of the two methods? Can I assign the order of the two method？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can add multiple @BeforeClass methods in a class. They will run in alphabetical order as per method name e.g. in following example the order of execution will be,

1. setUp1()
2. setUp2()
3. queryAcquirerInfoById()

```
public class TestBase{

     @BeforeClass
     protected void setUp2() throws Exception {}

     @BeforeClass
     protected void setUp1() throws Exception {}

      @Test
      public void queryAcquirerInfoById(){
            }
        }
```

However, you can prioritize the execution of @BeforeClass methods using 'dependsOnMethods' option, like if you write

```
public class TestBase{

     @BeforeClass (dependsOnMethods = { "setUp1" })
     protected void setUp2() throws Exception {}

     @BeforeClass
     protected void setUp1() throws Exception {}

      @Test
      public void queryAcquirerInfoById(){
            }
        }
```

then setUp1() will run before setUp2()

Comment: Execute me, there is an another question.When I put the multiple @BeforeClass  in different class(one is father class, one is the child).
public class Father{
 /@BeforeClass
    protected void zBeforeClass() {
        System.out.println("aBeforeClass");
    }
}


public class Child extend Father{
 /@BeforeClass
    protected void aBeforeClass() {
        System.out.println("aBeforeClass");
    }
}

the aBeforeClass in Child will run after the zBeforeClass in father. I run this test in Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

It was [asked in testng group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/xtP9YYXAElw), and suggested to use single method calling multiple methods with order you want:

> use the simplest method possible:
>
> ```
> @BeforeClass
> public static void method1() {
>   ...
>   method2();
>   method3();
> }
> ```

In your case

```
@BeforeClass
protected void setUpAll() throws Exception {
 setUp();
 setUp2()
 }
protected void setUp() throws Exception {}

protected void setUp2() throws Exception {}
```

Comment: In my project, there is a parent class which has a method with the annotation '@BeforeClass', and I donot want to override the method. So I write a new method with the annotation.

Comment: @qyanqing call in parent also an abstract empty method, that you will implement